# How to remove the mounted Google drive in local PC

Tags: google-drive, windows

I have a question about new Google drive for PC

The other day, I installed new google drive for PC in my PC.
Then, the Google drive were connected on the PC as a new drive.
I only need folders for syncing.
I want to disconnect this connected drive,
but I can't remove it even if I look at the settings.

Does anyone know any solution?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the moment, probably the only way to unmount these virtual drives is to quit Google Desktop.

The new version of Google Desktop uses a customized version of the FUSE to create these virtual drives as a mounted file system. Unmounting the virtual disk will mess up Google Desktop, so it is grayed out.

Google has chosen make things difficult for the user any control over these drives that one normally expects to find with drives (or virtual drives), like mount and unmount, changing drive letters, renaming the mounted folder, changing the icon, etc.

[They have provided for some tweaking via the registry on Windows](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7644837?hl=en#defaultMountPoint_note) (and .plists on MacOS). [This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/gsuite/comments/p25ba6/removing_the_g_drive_that_drive_for_desktop/) has [this solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/gsuite/comments/p25ba6/comment/hct3439/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) which will let you at least hide the drives:

> Create a empty folder, e.g. `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\GDrive`
>
> Open registry editor with Start -> `regedit.msc` or simply run `regedit`
>
> Go to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies]`
>
> Add the two keys `Google\DriveFS` with right-click and **New -> Key**. You
> should now have `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\DriveFS]`
>
> Inside that key add a new string value with **New -> String Value** with
> `DefaultMountPoint` with value `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\GDrive`. This will
> mount the virtual drive into that location
>
> Restart Google Drive
>
> Verify that your files are still synced and the virtual drive does not
> appear anymore. The shortcut to "My Drive" is now created in folder
> you created

Comment: Did you come up with any way to keep these files and folders available even when Google Drive isn't running? I redirect my personal folders (Desktop, Documents, etc) to this path, and if Google Drive isn't running, like after a reboot, my Desktop is all screwed up because the files are completely gone. Even when they are set to always be available offline. This change in behavior is forcing me to move away from Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell Google Drive to use a folder in some hidden location (e.g. `%LocalAppData%\Google\DriveStreaming`) as a mounting point instead of a drive letter.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).